# while running Munit getting error "org.mule.runtime.api.exception.DefaultMuleException: Error while parsing script: %dw"

Tags: mule, dataweave, munit

Error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.mule.runtime.api.exception.DefaultMuleException: Error while parsing script: %dw 2.0
output application/json

fun splitByLoadNumber(aString) = ((aString splitBy "/")[5] splitBy "_")[2]
fun isCancelled(item) = item contains( "CANCELLED" )
var orderedData={ "files-list": payload."files-list" orderBy ((record,index) -> (record.lastModified)) groupBy splitByLoadNumber($.fileName) pluck $ map $[-1] }
---

"files-list":orderedData."files-list" filter !isCancelled($.fileName)
        at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.LazyMuleArtifactContext.lambda$applyLifecycle$8(LazyMuleArtifactContext.java:239)
INFO  2020-04-28 16:34:04,122 [munit.01] org.mule.munit.runner.remote.api.server.RunnerServer: Waiting for client connection
        at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.context.DefaultMuleContext.withLifecycleLock(DefaultMuleContext.java:510)
```

sample payload

```
#[%dw 2.0 output application/json --- { "files-list": [ { "fileName": "abc/out/edm/pallets/input/abc_Load_DB1902717_COMPLETE_20200415155427_115768.xml", "fileSize": 2001, "lastModified": "2020-04-16T12:26:37" }, { "fileName": "abc/out/edm/pallets/input/abc_Load_DB1902718_CANCELLED_20200415155427_115768.xml", "fileSize": 2001, "lastModified": "2020-04-17T12:26:38" } ] }]
```

Comment: sample payload #[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
  "files-list": [
    {
      "fileName": "abc/out/edm/pallets/input/abc_Load_DB1902717_COMPLETE_20200415155427_115768.xml",
      "fileSize": 2001,
      "lastModified": "2020-04-16T12:26:37"
    },
    {
      "fileName": "abc/out/edm/pallets/input/abc_Load_DB1902718_CANCELLED_20200415155427_115768.xml",
      "fileSize": 2001,
      "lastModified": "2020-04-17T12:26:38"
    }
  ]
}]

Comment: what version of Mule and MUnit was used?

Comment: I am using mule Version: 7.4.1 studio and munit 2.2.1

Comment: 7.4.1 is the version of Anypoint Studio. It doesn't usually affect the execution of the application or tests. We need to know the version of Mule Runtime used to execute.

Comment: Mule version is 4.2.2

Comment: Thanks. Could you add a few more lines of the previous lines of the log?

Comment: INFO  2020-04-28 17:33:41,383 [munit.01] org.mule.munit.runner.remote.api.server.RunnerServer: Waiting for client connection
"files-list":orderedData."files-list" filter !isCancelled($.fileName)
INFO  2020-04-28 17:33:41,387 [Embedded] org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArchiveDeployer: ================== Request to Undeploy Artifact: prc-pal

Comment: As limit is very less in comment so unable to send in details

Comment: You can edit your question and add the details there. I did that on your behalf for your sample input.

Answer (score 0):

This error message "Error while parsing script" is generally seen when there are 1 or more **empty DWL files**. Sometimes there could be several different DWL files containing folders in which 1 or more empty DWL files could be present. Once, the empty files are deleted or a script is added in it, the error will be resolved